# How to get the list of all User Federation Providers associated with a realm?

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak 11.0 and looking for an approach to get all the user federation providers associated to a given Realm. On my setup I have created a dummy Realm and added to it a dummy Federation.

I used the [Keycloak Admin Rest API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_userfederationproviderrepresentation) to get the Realm and then looking into the json `userFederationProviders` field, but nothing is there. I have also tried with the following Java code:

```
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserFederationProviderRepresentation;

public class Key {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
                "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                "dummyRealm",
                "admin",
                "a",
                "admin-cli");
        RealmRepresentation realm = keycloak.realm("dummyRealm").toRepresentation();
        for(UserFederationProviderRepresentation s : realm.getUserFederationProviders())
            System.out.println(s.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

However, I get a NPE because the `realm.getUserFederationProviders()` is null.

Is there any way to get the list of all userFederationProviders associated to a Realm without having to use the Keycloak Admin console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List realm [components](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_component_resource) and filter `type=org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider&parent=<realm name>`. Check browser network console and you will see that this API request is also made by Keycloak Admin console, when you visit User Federation configuration.